# Can I replace values in cells conditional on a string?

Tags: r

I am new to R and trying to create my own dataset by modifying Eurostat data. I now have regions with names such as AT111, AT112 and ITC11. I want to give each country a number, so that all regions from AT have a country code equal to 1.

For that I have added a new empty column to my dataset. Is there a way for me to do this:

```
NUTS3.3[NUTS3.3$geo == "AT111", "country"] <- 1
```

for all observations whose geo string contains "AT" at once?

I have >26 000 observations, so doing it for every single regional code would be tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can get the `substr` of the column and do the `==`

```
NUTS3.3$country[substr(NUTS3.3$geo, 1, 2)=="AT"] <- 1
```